# Secure way to sign a Transaction in a polling Service

Tags: transactions, development, eosjs

assume i have written an polling service in nodejs which i would like to run on an aws e2 instance (t2.nano/t2.micro). This service will observe a specific account every 10sec or so for incoming actions (interested in eosio.token transfer) using `cleos get actions tokenxchange 1 0` from [Example Exchange](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Tutorial-Exchange-Deposit-Withdraw#machine-readable-account-history-json). After the Polling i will get a json and would check if there are any eosio.token transfers and if, then i will extract the memo data...

If i have done everything i would like to execute a transaction from this service but to do this i need to sign this transaction and to do this i would need to hardcode my privatekey. Is there a better way to sign a transaction automatically? Would it be safe to hardcode a private key in this service because amazon firewall etc? (Naturally i would create an extra account with only the rights to execute the transaction it is allowed to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exchange tutorials, you can either use a hot wallet that is unlocked via cleos and wallet only listening for a connection from localhost or use a hardware wallet for signing. The latter is not an option in a AWS instance.